# How do I escape entries of a table created with the 'table' CI library?

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter, escaping

I'm trying to select a whole SQL table and display it in a view, for that I found the CodeIgniter library table to be very convenient, however the data is not escaped and I don't know how and at which step I should escape it.

In the model:

```
public function get_all_query()
{
    $query = $this->db->get("test.navires");
    return $query;
}
```

In the controller :

```
$this->load->library('table');
$data['ships_table'] = $this->table->generate($this->ships_model->get_all_query());
$this->load->view("ships", $data);
```

In the view :

```
<?=$ships_table?>
```

Of course I could just build the table manually and escape myself and there would be no trouble, but I'm curious to see how to do it this way.

Thanky you.